# Selenium Webdriver Python - how do I drag and drop a photo that is in my mac to a web photo upload interface?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

How can I drag and drop a photo that in my finder(mac) to a web upload interface (droppable).
I attached below the screenshots of the scenarios I want to do and the source code of droppable interface.

I used action chain but I I'm not sure I understand the parameters (source, target)

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

action = ActionChains(driver)
action.drag_and_drop('source','target').perform()
```

[image: Screenshot_1]

[image: screenshot_2]

Comment: I'm not sure if `drag_and_drop` can use something different then object on page. Often `drag_and_drop` on page uses some hidden `<input type="file">` and it can be easier to send file path as text directly to this input.

Comment: I see, what do you propose to solve this scenario?

I've already used Xpath to locate items but it didn't work for almost with drag and drop upload photo functionality.

Comment: it is hard to say anything if you didn't add in question url for this page and we can't see it in web browser.

Comment: unfortunately, this interface is only available in Google My Business, so you have to log in to be able to display it (having a Gmail email address is ok), otherwise could I have your email address so that I can give access in an already existing Google My business listing that we can use to do the test, you can send me this to zahoavao0@gmail.com if it's ok for you. thanks